How to add an element under a fluid embed YT video
I have a fluid iframe containing a YT video here, and I'm trying to get the span containing the description below to "stick" to the bottom of the iframe, whatever the length of the text.
Here's the code so you'll have a better idea of what I'm talking about.
HTML
<div class="content">
  <div class="video-container">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/kTbVbT9QDkc" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <span>My comment or description</span>
  </div>
</div>

CSS
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.video-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.video-container > span {
    background-color: #f0f2f5;
    padding: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -26px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

So I understand that the problem comes from the fact that both elements (iframe and span) are positioned in "absolute", and I'm looking for an alternative solution that I can't find.
Of course, I could put the span outside the div.video-container, right after it, but I've already got quite a few videos published, so if there's a solution, it would save me a lot of work. 
I made a CODEPEN
Thanks

The only solution I've found so far (here) is to use "aspect-ratio". It's compatible for 94% of users, according to CanIUse. So I'm not changing anything in the HTML, just a few lines in the CSS:
.video-container {
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  width: 100%;
}
.video-container iframe {   
  display: block; /* This is to remove the weird space just below the iframe */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.video-container > span {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
}

So now the span will stick just below the iframe, whatever its content. It's not a perfect solution, as it poses compatibility problems with some (old) browsers, but in my case it's better than the absolute positioning solution.
